# Multi-group regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to parse some text, which consists of a six digit code, an **optional** confirmation string (one of 'ok', 'yes' or 'no'), followed by some free text. So it might look like:

```
123456 Ok Mary had a little lamb
```

... but might equally be

```
123456 Mary had a little lamb
```

...and I'd need each of those three parts captured separately.

I've got this regex:

```
/^\s*?(\d\d\d\s?\d\d\d)\s*?(yes|no|ok)?\s*?(.*?)$/i
```

...which doesn't work! I can tweak it so that it works if you always have the 'yes', 'no' or 'ok', but that is an optional element.

Any thoughts very much appreciated.

Comment: Please precise the language when you use the regex tag : as regex flavors have different capabilities it makes the question more easily answerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem is that `\s*?` doesn't make sense, you want `\s*` : as `*` means 0 or more it already makes the space optional.

Use

```
/^\s*?(\d{3}\s?\d{3})\s*(yes|no|ok)?\s*(.*)$/i
```

For example in JavaScript,

```
var str = '123456 Ok Mary had a little lamb';
var arr = str.match(/^\s*?(\d{3}\s?\d{3})\s*(yes|no|ok)?\s*(.*)$/i).slice(1);
```

gives

```
["123456", "Ok", " Mary had a little lamb"]
```

Comment: If you want to strip out the field separators, maybe \s* instead of \s*?, and the final (.*?)$ could be (.*)$

Comment: @sln Right : I had fixed the first one but didn't notice the (not bugging) other ones.